# Understanding IPv6 Address

Tags: ipv6

My IPv6 address is like this (some digits changed):

2001:569:78f0:ca00:bcaa:d016:4

...as reported by whatismyipaddress.com.

This is strange because I understand that there should be eight blocks not seven. I added this to the .htaccess file of my website and it successfully blocks me from accessing the site:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 2001:569:78f0:ca00:bcaa:d016:4
allow from all
```

Question: What is the full eight block equivalent of my IPv6 address?

Comment: I think you may be missing a double colon somewhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation

Comment: No that's not it, whatismyipaddress.com reports my address without any double colons and .htaccess successfully blocks my IP address with the seven groups.

Comment: Please also take a look at http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/214507

Comment: @kasperd I'm not sure how that helps but if you are referring to not releasing personal information then, thanks, but I had said "My IPv6 address is like this (**some digits changed**)".

Comment: @Carbonsink Did you pay attention to the part saying: **Never obfuscate using IP addresses not controlled by you or your organization and which are not reserved for use in examples or documentation.**?

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks for pointing to the specific part you wanted to me to read (the second time around).

Answer (score 3):

As described for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation), you can shorten these addresses and omit zeros if it is unambiguous.

For example:

> The loopback address, 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001, may be abbreviated to ::1 by using both rules.

So give it a try once more to have a look at your real IP if you don't miss some colon `:` or something else.

Comment: No that's not it, whatismyipaddress.com reports my address without any double colons and .htaccess successfully blocks my IP address with the seven groups.